# How to split a tree in branches based on depth

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, tree, logic

I'm unsure if this is a hard problem, or I'm just way too rusty in DSA, but I can't find a way to write a function to split a tree in multiple branches, based on an arbitrary value of depth.

**What I mean is:** I want to write a function `split_tree` that receives AT LEAST, the parameters: `tree` and `level` the latter being the level of depth in the tree. The function should explore the tree until it reaches the determined level and then returns a copy of that branch, with all the unrelated nodes trimmed. Repeat it until all nodes of the same level are done.

Consider the Tree in the image bellow.

[image: Tree]

The `level` determines which nodes are the base nodes (or relevant nodes) for splitting the branches. Considering the ROOT node is 0, if `level=1` the base nodes are **B, C and D**, if `level=2` the base nodes would be **E, F, C, H and I**.

So, calling `split_tree(tree, level=1)` would return three different branches:

```
[ROOT, B, [E, F]]
[ROOT, C]
[ROOT, D, [H, I, [J, K]]]
```

While calling `split_tree(tree, level=2)` would return five different branches:

```
[ROOT, B, E]
[ROOT, B, F]
[ROOT, C]
[ROOT, D, H]
[ROOT, D, I, [J, K]]
```

Notice that

- If a branch doesn't reach the depth of `level` it returns a branch that is as dept as it could be. E.g: **[ROOT, C]**
- If a base node has child nodes, they are included in the branch. E.g: **[ROOT, D, I, [J, K]]**
- All siblings of the base node and other unrelated branches got trimmed.

I specially appreciate any help in pseudo code or python, but feel free to use whatever.

Comment: I don't get why in the level=1 example, `[ROOT, B, [E, F]]` has `E` and `F` in a sublist, while `[ROOT, D, H, I, [J, K]]` does not combine `H` and `I` in a sublist.

Comment: This is they way I found to represent that when splitting the branch, the child nodes (of the base node) should be preserved. In the `level=2` example, the base node is `I`, so its ancestors are `D > K > ROOT`, while it's children are `[J, K]`. So I'm representing `[ROOT, D, I, [J, K]]`.  On the level 1 **there is mistake**, the correct would be `[ROOT, D, [H, I, [J, K]]]`

Comment: Fixed, I believe now level 1 is represented correctly, as the base node is `D`, both `H` and `I` are children, and `J` and `K` are grandchildren. `[ROOT, D, [H, I, [J, K]]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation in Python:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, *children):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children

def children_to_nested_list(children):
    for child in children:
        yield child.value
        if child.children:
            yield list(children_to_nested_list(child.children))
 
def split_tree(tree, level):
    if not tree:
        return
    if not tree.children:
        yield [tree.value]
        return
    if level == 0:
        yield [tree.value, list(children_to_nested_list(tree.children))]
        return
    for child in tree.children:
        for path in split_tree(child, level - 1):
            yield [tree.value, *path]
```

Here is a run on the example tree:

```py
tree = Node("ROOT",    
           Node("B",
               Node("E"),
               Node("F")
           ),
           Node("C"),
           Node("D",
               Node("H"),
               Node("I",
                   Node("J"),
                   Node("K")
               )
           )
       )

print("level 1:")
for branch in split_tree(tree, 1):
    print(branch)
print("level 2:")
for branch in split_tree(tree, 2):
    print(branch)
```

This outputs:

```
level 1:
['ROOT', 'B', ['E', 'F']]
['ROOT', 'C']
['ROOT', 'D', ['H', 'I', ['J', 'K']]]
level 2:
['ROOT', 'B', 'E']
['ROOT', 'B', 'F']
['ROOT', 'C']
['ROOT', 'D', 'H']
['ROOT', 'D', 'I', ['J', 'K']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The function should recursively merge the paths with the current name when the level is greater than 0, or otherwise recursively append the child nodes in a list after the current name:

```
def split_tree(tree, level=0):
    for name, branch in tree.items():
        if branch:
            paths = split_tree(branch, level - 1)
            if level > 0:
                yield from ([name, *path] for path in paths)
            else:
                yield [name, [node for path in paths for node in path]]
        else:
            yield [name]
```

so that given a tree structure of:

```
tree = {
    'ROOT': {
        'B': {
            'E': {},
            'F': {}
        },
        'C': {},
        'D': {
            'H': {},
            'I': {
                'J': {},
                'K': {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

calling:

```
print(*split_tree(tree, 1), sep='\n')`
```

outputs:

```
['ROOT', 'B', ['E', 'F']]
['ROOT', 'C']
['ROOT', 'D', ['H', 'I', ['J', 'K']]]
```

and calling:

```
print(*split_tree(tree, 2), sep='\n')
```

outputs:

```
['ROOT', 'B', 'E']
['ROOT', 'B', 'F']
['ROOT', 'C']
['ROOT', 'D', 'H']
['ROOT', 'D', 'I', ['J', 'K']]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/JZ3HaM